# tqdm function with image data generator in a loop

Tags: image, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

Can someone explain the code in the photo, I do not understand how tqdm is used here. From my knowledge tqdm is used for iteration, so what does it iterate in the generator??
[image]

Comment: replace that screenshot with the text it contains.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.